# SQL trimming syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, trim

I've just finished 'SAM's Teach Yourself SQL in 24 Hours' book, and I've been given the task of listing which of our active site's "site_code" match their respective "site_path"s with the prefix '/var/www/html' removed. I've been stuck for the past hour or so trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and don't know what else to try at this point.

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT site_name FROM example_tbl
WHERE active = 1
AND site_code IN
(SELECT TRIM(LEADING '/var/www/html/' FROM site_path) FROM example_tbl;);
```

Trying to run that's giving me this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

I'm using Mysql ver 14.14 Dustrib 5.5.38 on Ubuntu ver 14.10

The nested query works fine by itself, and if I get rid of everything from 'AND' on, the first part works fine as well, so I'm not sure why they won't work together :\

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Sorry, I should have been more specific!
'site_code', 'site_path' and 'site_name' are all columns in the table 'example_tbl', and I'm trying to get a list site names to print out like this

Input: /var/www/html/example.company.com
Output: example.example.com

EDIT2:
Oh and for that example above:
The 'site_name' would be: example.company.com
The 'site_code' would be: example
And the 'site_path' would be: /var/www/html/example.company.com

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Is `site_path` a column or a table or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra semicolon.

```
SELECT site_name FROM example_tbl
WHERE active = 1
AND site_code IN
(SELECT TRIM(LEADING '/var/www/html/' FROM site_path) FROM example_tbl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
I'd also mixed up site_name and site_code, but I managed to figure out the rest from there :)

Comment: Well, there was no way I could have known that. I'm glad that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses the MySQL `SUBSTRING` function instead of `TRIM`:

```
SELECT site_name
FROM example_tbl
WHERE active = 1 AND
SUBSTRING(site_path, 1, 13) = '/var/www/html' AND
SUBSTRING(site_path, 14) = site_code
```

I don't think you needed a subquery to solve your problem.  Also, I included a condition in the `WHERE` clause to also check that the `site_path` begins with 'var/www/html'.  If you expect all your sites to begin with this, then feel free to remove this condition.